# How does Guava Set difference work?

Tags: java, guava

when are two objects considered to be different in `Sets.difference`.When they have a different hash code or when `object.equals` returns a false.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> The returned set contains all elements that are contained by `set1` and not contained by `set2`

It thus means that the rule depends on the type of the two sets. If the Set is a HashSet, for example, `equals()` will be used. If the set is a TreeSet, `compareTo()` (or the comparator's `compare()` method) will be used. If an IdentityHashSet is used, the identity of the object will be used.

`hashCode()` will never be used by any (correct) Set implementation to determine equality, because two unequal objects may have the same hashCode.

Comment: Looks like a typo in that last paragraph. What did you mean? Not clear.

Comment: There are an infinity of potential objects. There are only 2^32 possible hashCodes. So implementing equality by comparing hashCodes can't work. A HashSet only reduces the number of potentially equal candidates thanks to hashCode. Eventually, equals is used to tell if two objects are equal, even if they have the same hasCode

Comment: i went with this aprroach and tried a Sets.difference on two hashsets of some custom class.I added a System.out.println("hashcode") to the hashcode and System.out.println('equals') to the equals method.i got a console result like this _Calling difference
hashCode
Equals
hashCode
Equals
hashCode
Equals_ is it because hashcode is called when objects are iterated? i have to check with tree sets.

Comment: i think i checks the hashcode and then checks the equals...please confirm

Comment: I have already confirmed: A HashSet only reduces the number of potentially equal candidates thanks to hashCode. Eventually, equals is used to tell if two objects are equal, even if they have the same hashCode.

Comment: ok. i used a class with fields implementing the interface.Two objects extending this class wont have the same hashcode and their equals is not reliable.So both hashcode and equals play a part here.

Comment: `Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
 set1.add("123");
 set1.add("777");
 set1.add("888");
 
 Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
 set1.add("123");
 set1.add("999");
 set1.add("000");
 
 System.out.println(Sets.difference(set1, set2));` My output is [888, 777, 123, 000, 999]. I really dont understand the difference here. As per the documentation it is suppose to return only 777 and 888 . What did I misunderstood ?

Comment: @sathishvisa Your set2 is empty. You only add strings to set1.